# Parallelize slow functions that needs to be run only every X iterations in order to not slow the loop

Tags: python, parallel-processing, multiprocessing, face-recognition, opencv

### The project

I am conducting a project where I need to both detect faces (bounding boxes and landmarks) and perform face recognition (identify a face). The detection is really fast (it takes not even a few milliseconds on my laptop) but the recognition can be really slow (about 0.4 seconds on my laptop). I am using the `face_recognition`  Python library to do so. After a few tests, I discovered that it is the embedding of the image that is slow.

Here is an example code to try it out for yourself :

```py
# Source : https://pypi.org/project/face-recognition/
import face_recognition

known_image = face_recognition.load_image_file("biden.jpg")
biden_encoding = face_recognition.face_encodings(known_image)[0]

image = face_recognition.load_image_file("your_file.jpg")
face_locations = face_recognition.face_locations(image)
face_landmarks_list = face_recognition.face_landmarks(image)

unknown_encoding = face_recognition.face_encodings(image)[0]
results = face_recognition.compare_faces([biden_encoding], unknown_encoding)
```

### The problem

What I need to do is to process a video (30 FPS), therefore 0.4s of computation is unacceptable. The idea that I have is that the recognition will only need to be run a few times and not every frame since from one frame to another, if there are no *cuts* in the video, a given head will be close to its previous position. Therefore, the first time the head appears, we run the recognition which is very slow but then for the next X frames, we won't have to since we'll detect that the position is close to the previous one, therefore it must be the same person that moved. Of course, this approach is not perfect but seems to be a good compromise and I would like to try it.

The only problem is that by doing so the video is smooth until a head appears, then the video freezes because of the recognition and then becomes smooth again. This is where I would like to introduce multiprocessing, I would like to be able to compute the recognition in parallel of looping through the frame of the video. If I manage to do so, I will then only have to process a few frames in advance so that when a face shows up it already computed its recognition a few seconds ago **during several frames** so that we did not see a reduced frame rate.

### Simple formulation

Therefore here is what I have (in python pseudo code so that it is clearer):

```py
def slow_function(image):
    # This function takes a lot of time to compute and would normally slow down the loop
    return Recognize(image)
    
# Loop that we need to maintain at a given speed
person_name = "unknown"
frame_index = -1
while True:
    frame_index += 1
    frame = new_frame() # this is not important and therefore not detailes
    
    # Every ten frames, we run a heavy function
    if frame_index % 10 == 0:
        person_name = slow_function(image)

    # each frame we use the person_name even if we only compute it every so often
    frame.drawText(person_name)
```

And I would like to do something like this :

```py
def slow_function(image):
    # This function takes a lot of time to compute and would normally slow down the loop
    return Recognize(image)
    
# Loop that we need to maintain at a given speed
person_name = "unknown"
frame_index = -1
while True:
    frame_index += 1
    frame = new_frame() # this is not important and therefore not detailes
    
    # Every ten frames, we run a heavy function
    if frame_index % 10 == 0:
        DO slow_function(image) IN parallel WITH CALLBACK(person_name = result)

    # each frame we use the person_name even if we only compute it every so often
    frame.drawText(person_name)
```

The goal is to compute a slow function over several iterations of a loop.

### What I have tried

I looked up `multiprocessing`  and `Ray` but I did not find examples of what I wanted to do. Most of the time I found people using `multiprocessing`  to compute at the same time the result of a function for different inputs. This is not what I want. I want to have in parallel a loop and a process that accepts data from the loop (a frame), do some computation, and returns a value to the loop without interrupting or slowing down the loop (or at least, spreading the slow down rather than having one really slow iteration and 9 fast ones).

Comment: I don't understand what you want to do and how it is different than mentioned examples in `multiprocessing`. As for me you also run the same function with different inputs but you run new process every 10 loops - but it is still similar to examples which runs new function in the same time. Every 10 loops you can run new `Process()` with different inputs.

Comment: Could you give me such an example, please? Because I could not find one

Answer (score 0):

I think I found pretty much how to do what I want. Here is an example:

```py
from multiprocessing import Pool
import time

# This seems to me more precise than time.sleep()
def sleep(duration, get_now=time.perf_counter):
    now = get_now()
    end = now + duration
    while now < end:
        now = get_now()
        

def myfunc(x):
    time.sleep(1)
    return x
 
def mycallback(x):
     print('Callback for i = {}'.format(x))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    pool=Pool()
    
    # Approx of 5s in total
    # Without parallelization, this should take 15s
    t0 = time.time()
    titer = time.time()
    for i in range(100):
        if i% 10 == 0: pool.apply_async(myfunc, (i,), callback=mycallback)
        sleep(0.05) # 50ms
        print("- i =", i, "/ Time iteration:", 1000*(time.time()-titer), "ms")
        titer = time.time()
        
    print("\n\nTotal time:", (time.time()-t0), "s")
    
    t0 = time.time()
    for i in range(100):
        sleep(0.05)
    print("\n\nBenchmark sleep time time:", 10*(time.time()-t0), "ms")
```

Of course, I will need to add flags so that I do not write a value with the callback at the same time that I read it in the loop.

Comment: you shoulr rather `Process` instead of `Pool` because usually create only 4 processes (if you have CPU with 4 cores) and when you try to run 5th process then it has to wait until other processes stop running. And you may need `Queue` to send value from processes to main thread. And using `Queue` you can check queue in main `for`-loop to get current value - so it will not get it when you read other element.

Comment: Thanks, I tried this and at the beginning, it did not work, it was even slower. But that was on Windows, after swapping to Ubuntu it worked fine! Thanks again